# Display a message for a while at the end of a timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I would have liked to know how to display a message at the end of my timer for a certain time (1 minutes) and then loop again.

Example of the desired process:

- Start of timer 2 minutes ("02:00")
- Timer replaced by a message ("wait...") at the end once it is finished for 1 minute and all this done in a loop

Thanks you, Quentin S.

I have already realized the timer but I miss more than the monitor tag is replaced by the message I want to put for 1 minute before starting the process from the beginning

```html
<div><span id="time">02:00</span></div>
```

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
        }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var twoMinutes = 60 * 2,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(twoMinutes, display);
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this by stopping the interval once the time has reached zero and restarting it after one minute using `setTimeout`

By the way, your code has a little bug, the callback provided for `setInterval` does not run when the interval starts, but only after one interval (one second in your case). I've fixed that here.

Also I have adjusted the times to reduce waiting.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display, pause) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    const updateTime = function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
            display.textContent = "wait...";
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            setTimeout(function () {
                startTimer(duration, display, pause)
            }, pause*1000)
        }
    }
    const intervalId = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    updateTime();
}

window.onload = function () {
    var interval = 4,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(interval, display, 2);
};
```

```html
<div><span id="time">XX:XX</span></div>
```